# Getting the user's local time into my Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone

How do I get the user's local time into my Rails app?

I can't ask for their timezone, nor do I want to use some API to get the time zone from the ip.

I think this might involve passing the Javascript date to my Rails app- how do I do that well? I can do it with therubyracer in my view, but that is messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the user date through a form, you can have a hidden form field and use javascript to enter the user's time into that field.

Alternatively, on `window.load` you can send a `AJAX` call(or similar) to some custom URL with the date-time in the params.

Comment: var today = new Date(); today.getTimezoneOffset();